# Prevent .htaccess 301 redirects on subdomain

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I have 301 redirects which direct `/index.html` to `/site` folder and when I created a subdomain it also redirects the link to `/site` which causes `404 Not Found`.

For example: `members.mysite.com` redirects to `members.mysite/site` which causes 404 error
can I add execption for specific forlder or something without changing the redirect.

.htaccess content:

```
AddType text/x-server-parsed-html .htm .html
RedirectMatch 301  ^/index.html(.*)$ /site$1
```

Answer (score 3):

*.htaccess* rules apply to every subfolder that are within the folder with that *.htaccess* file. To stop your root *.htaccess* file affecting your subdomains, you should create your subdomain folders outside of the `public_html` folder on your server.

Also the problem with your redirect is that you are using redirect match, try a redirect that specifies the absolute path, such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /site? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```